# Spring Scheduling annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i want to use spring scheduling in annotation . but its start with 2 thread by default .

here the code :

```
//@Scheduled(fixedDelay=20000, initialDelay=30000)
      @Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)     
     public void updateEmployeeInventory(){
         System.out.println("Started fixed rate  job:::::::::::"+new Date());  
}
```

when run this its started with 2 thread  :

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Started fixed rate job:::::::::::Fri Oct 10 16:56:28 IST 2014
Oct 10, 2014 4:56:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Started fixed rate job:::::::::::Fri Oct 10 16:56:29 IST 2014
```

and in AppConfig.java file :

```
@Bean
public SMSPullerJob SMSPullerJob() {
    return new SMSPullerJob();
}
```

how to set thread pool size in appconfig.java  file i am working with only

Comment: Make sure that your bean is only instantiated twice. If it is annotated with `@Component` and you are also scanning it will be instantiated twice and you will get 2 jobs. The same goes for if the configuration is loaded multiple times (once by the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet`.).

Comment: you are right . but how to avoid 2 time .

Comment: Don't load it twice… Don't scan for the same beans in both contexts and make sure that your `AppConfig` isn't loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` as this will duplicate basically all your beans (rendering everything in the `ContextLoaderListener` useless).

Comment: its initialize like this:  INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext : Started fixed rate job:::::::::::Fri Oct 10 16:56:28 IST 2014   /n INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'  Started fixed rate job:::::::::::Fri Oct 10 16:56:29 IST 2014

Comment: which one should stop ?